# Different variance estimator for multilevel ordinal logistic regression in Stata and R

Tags: r, stata, multilevel-analysis, ordered-logit

I estimate a multilevel ordinal logistic regression models in Stata and R, and receive different estimators for the variance and the covariance of the latent variable of the higher level.
Among other data, I use this Stata datafile (from Stata help for meologit):
http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/tvsfpors.dta
I estimate (among others) this model:

```
# R formula syntax
library(ordinal)
library(readstata13)
mydata <- read.dta13(file = "http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/tvsfpors.dta",  
                     convert.factors = FALSE)
res <- clmm(as.factor(thk) ~ prethk + cc + tv + (1 | school), mydata, nAGQ  =7)
summary(res)

* Stata equation
webuse tvsfpors
meologit thk prethk cc tv || school:
```

The columns in the variance-covariance-matrix for the variance of the latent higher-level variable seem to differ systematically. The covariances differ by an identical constant, and the variances (of the variance) themselves by the squared term of the constant. The constant differ dependent on the data and model structure.

Does anyone know the source of this difference?

This is the variance-covariance-matrix for the estimation described above for R:
Here is the var-cov-matrix for R

```
> vcov(m1)
                1|2          2|3          3|4        prethk            cc            tv           ST1
1|2     0.023567239  0.022089030  0.022112907  0.0030638974  0.0105995218  0.0111725311 -0.0043760134
2|3     0.022089030  0.023866162  0.023611332  0.0033154896  0.0111666464  0.0111977570 -0.0031374135
3|4     0.022112907  0.023611332  0.026259339  0.0036017005  0.0116806803  0.0112381854 -0.0018698361
prethk  0.003063897  0.003315490  0.003601701  0.0015113830  0.0003659838  0.0001657595 -0.0009479396
cc      0.010599522  0.011166646  0.011680680  0.0003659838  0.0216625428 -0.0002137013  0.0004195043
tv      0.011172531  0.011197757  0.011238185  0.0001657595 -0.0002137013  0.0214436765 -0.0012672853
ST1    -0.004376013 -0.003137414 -0.001869836 -0.0009479396  0.0004195043 -0.0012672853  0.0642318747
```

This is the analogue in Stata

```
. matrix list e(V), nohalf

symmetric e(V)[7,7]
                                   thk:          thk:          thk:         cut1:         cut2:         cut3:  var(_cons~):
                                prethk            cc            tv         _cons         _cons         _cons         _cons
              thk:prethk     .00151138     .00036598     .00016576      .0030639     .00331549      .0036017    -.00015693
                  thk:cc     .00036598     .02166253    -.00021371     .01059951     .01116663     .01168067     .00006945
                  thk:tv     .00016576    -.00021371     .02144367     .01117254     .01119776     .01123818    -.00020983
              cut1:_cons      .0030639     .01059951     .01117254     .02356724     .02208902      .0221129    -.00072444
              cut2:_cons     .00331549     .01116663     .01119776     .02208902     .02386615     .02361132     -.0005194
              cut3:_cons      .0036017     .01168067     .01123818      .0221129     .02361132     .02625932    -.00030956
var(_cons[school]):_cons    -.00015693     .00006945    -.00020983    -.00072444     -.0005194    -.00030956     .00176027
```

Note that the column and row order is different. My question points at the diffference between the rows/columns of the variable var(_cons[school]) in the Stata matrix and ST1 in the R matrix.

Comment: You might want to add the output of your models, esp. the variance-covariance matrix. When I run these models in R and Stata, I get almost identical results.